How to determine the root cause of intermittent error in Gradle: "Could not import Ant build file"
This can work for weeks, and then I'll get a report from a colleague:
Build file '/Users/my_colleague/.../build.gradle' line: 380

A problem occurred evaluating project ':our_project'.
> Could not import Ant build file '/correct/path/to/build.xml'.

(I'd share a build.gradle, but we have dozens, so.... this is a massive corporate codebase that can't be distilled and also needs to remain at Gradle v7.3.3, unfortunately)
So, I ask colleague to:

./gradlew --stop to ensure all daemons are stopped
delete all folders/files in .gradle folder in the project
delete .gradle folder in /home/username
Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
reboot
re-install Android Studio

The solution results above also seem to vary, and running with any kind of stack trace stops while trying to import the Ant build file.
Question:

Is there a way to determine the root cause?

Code:
// Gradle 7.3.3 -- Groovy
def pathToBuildXML = "/correct/path/to/build.xml"

// Rename ant targets with dashes ("-") to use underscores ("_")
ant.importBuild(pathToBuildXML) { antTargetName ->
    antTargetName.replace("-", "_")
}

